# custom exception mapping in spring security xml

Tags: spring-security

### I am giving below snippet in spring security.xml

```
<!-- Exception Mapping configuration -->
    <bean id="securityExceptionTranslationHandler"
        class="com.abc.xyz.ExceptionMappingFailureHandler" >
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException">/408</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

---

I am getting error while starting tomcat itself saying :
Invalid property exceptionMappings of com.abc.xyz.ExceptionMappingFailureHandler class :Bean Property exceptionMappings is not writtable or has an invalid setter method .

What should be content of com.abc.xyz.ExceptionMappingFailureHandler class ?
Any  Help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should look something like this to work:

```
package com.abc.xyz;

public class ExceptionMappingFailureHandler {

    public void setExceptionMappings(Map mappings) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The important thing is that there is a setter with that name, it returns void, and accepts a single argument of type Map.